# Not able to use gpu with ray serve

Tags: deep-learning, huggingface-transformers, ray

I am using below code as suggested in https://docs.ray.io/en/master/serve/getting_started.html for my 2 gpus.

```
from starlette.requests import Request

import ray
from ray import serve

from transformers import pipeline
from parallel import *

@serve.deployment(num_replicas=2, ray_actor_options={"num_cpus": 0, "num_gpus": 1})
class Translator:
def init(self):
self.model = get_model()#pipeline("translation_en_to_fr", model="t5-small")

def translate(self, count: int) -> int:
    model_output =  predict(self.model, count)#self.model(text)
    return 'translation'

async def __call__(self, http_request: Request) -> str:
    count: str = await http_request.json()
    return self.translate(count)

translator = Translator.bind()
```

I have other file which loads the model and predict.
This is how, model is loaded:

```
def get_model():
model = LayoutLMv2ForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained(model_checkpoint_finetuned)
print('model loaded in device')
return model
```

I don't see any gpus being used while predicting. It just uses CPU.

Can anyone help here?

Comment: How did you create your cluster?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to make sure `model` is set on the device (i.e., via `model.to("cuda")`).

https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/perf_train_gpu_one

Comment: do u mean, set the model on multiple gpu e.g. model.to(cuda:0), model.to(cuda:1)? If thats the case, on which gpu should data be?